# How to combine several form objects into one?

Tags: 8, entities

i'm working with Drupal 8 and i want to combine the user form and a node creation form into my custom form.

So i've created the form skeleton :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\fritr_register_friterie\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Class RegisterFriterieForm.
 *
 * @package Drupal\fritr_register_friterie\Form
 */
class RegisterFriterieForm extends FormBase {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFormId() {
        return 'register_friterie_form';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $form = [];

//        $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm();

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    }

}
```

But i don't know how to import the user_profile form and the node creation form of a custom content that i've created in the back office.

I know drupal_get_form('form_id') is replaced in drupal 8 by `\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(class, parameter);`

Maybe it's something like this : `\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(Drupal\user\Form\UserForm::class);`

But i have not find the documentation which show all the locations of form or examples.... And i have not find how to load a node creation form :/

Can you help me please ? Thanks :)

EDIT : i've found how to include my node creation form (but i don't know how to modify my fields... D8 So complex u_u) by :

```
$type = node_type_load('friterie');
        $node = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->create(array(
          'type' => $type->id(),
        ));

        // OPTIONAL - Set default values for node fields
        // $node->set('field_age', "32") ;
        $node_create_form = \Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($node);  
        $form['friterie'] = array(
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => render($node_create_form),
        );
        return $form;
```

need to find how to load user_profile form ^^

Comment: It can be done, though it is complicated.

Comment: Loading and building the forms is easy. The problems lie in combining the submission and validation methods and the submission buttons.

Comment: try \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\custom\Form\NewsletterForm') where custom module name newletterform is form controller

Comment: @harsh getting the inner form is the easy part, see the answer below to understand the complexity of a full solution.

Comment: I want add the user_profile form. I know how to include custom modules form but not how to include user_profile form and a node creation form of a specific content type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've created a working example of a combined form object.
Please read the comments below if you want to understand how it works and the workarounds that were applied.

The gist can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Eyal-Shalev/617813dc859bdc62fe4fb9c631449d9b)

**Note: There may still be unforeseen issues with the solution below.**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\sandbox\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormState;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

class ComboForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * This constant is used as a key inside the main form state object to gather
   * all the inner form state objects.
   * @const
   * @see getInnerFormState()
   */
  const INNER_FORM_STATE_KEY = 'inner_form_state';

  const MAIN_SUBMIT_BUTTON = 'submit';

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface[]
   */
  protected $innerForms = [];

  /**
   * The ComboForm constructor needs to initialize the inner form objects
   * that this form will later use.
   *
   * Because both the user and the node forms are entity forms then an entity
   * object needs to be assigned to them.
   *
   * Because the node entity has bundle, the bundle (type) must be defined
   * before the form is generated.
   *
   * @TODO If the node type is customizable then a custom controller is needed.
   *
   * @TODO should this form allow edits? If so then the form objects should
   *       be assigned with the edited entities.
   */
  public function __construct() {
    $this->innerForms['user'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getFormObject('user', 'default')
      ->setEntity(User::create());

    $this->innerForms['node'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getFormObject('node', 'default')
      ->setEntity(Node::create([
        'type' => 'article'
      ]));
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return implode('__', [
      'combo_form',
      $this->innerForms['user']->getFormId(),
      $this->innerForms['node']->getFormId()
    ]);
  }

  /**
   * The build form needs to take care of the following:
   *   - Creating a custom form state object for each inner form (and keep it
   *     inside the main form state.
   *   - Generating a render array for each inner form.
   *   - Handle compatibility issues such as #process array and action elements.
   *
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['#process'] = \Drupal::service('element_info')->getInfoProperty('form', '#process', []);
    $form['#process'][] = '::processForm';

    foreach ($this->innerForms as $key => $inner_form_object) {
      $inner_form_state = static::createInnerFormState($form_state, $inner_form_object, $key);


      // By placing the actual inner form inside a container element (such as
      // details) we gain the freedom to alter the wrapper of the inner form
      // with little damage to the render element attributes of the inner form.
      $inner_form = ['#parents' => [$key]];
      $inner_form = $inner_form_object->buildForm($inner_form, $inner_form_state);
      $form[$key] = [
        '#type' => 'details',
        '#title' => $this->t('Inner form: %key', ['%key' => $key]),
        'form' => $inner_form
      ];

      $form[$key]['form']['#type'] = 'container';
      $form[$key]['form']['#theme_wrappers'] = \Drupal::service('element_info')->getInfoProperty('container', '#theme_wrappers', []);
      unset($form[$key]['form']['form_token']);

      // The process array is called from the FormBuilder::doBuildForm method
      // with the form_state object assigned to the this (ComboForm) object.
      // This results in a compatibility issues because these methods should
      // be called on the inner forms (with their assigned FormStates).
      // To resolve this we move the process array in the inner_form_state
      // object.
      if (!empty($form[$key]['form']['#process'])) {
        $inner_form_state->set('#process', $form[$key]['form']['#process']);
        unset($form[$key]['form']['#process']);
      }
      else {
        $inner_form_state->set('#process', []);
      }

      // The actions array causes a UX problem because there should only be a
      // single save button and not multiple.
      // The current solution is to move the #submit callbacks of the submit
      // element to the inner form element root.
      if (!empty($form[$key]['form']['actions'])) {
        if (isset($form[$key]['form']['actions'][static::MAIN_SUBMIT_BUTTON])) {
          $form[$key]['form']['#submit'] = $form[$key]['form']['actions'][static::MAIN_SUBMIT_BUTTON]['#submit'];
        }

        unset($form[$key]['form']['actions']);
      }
    }

    // Default action elements.
    $form['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'actions',
      static::MAIN_SUBMIT_BUTTON => [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Save'),
        '#validate' => ['::validateForm'],
        '#submit' => ['::submitForm']
      ]
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * This method will be called from FormBuilder::doBuildForm during the process
   * stage.
   * In here we call the #process callbacks that were previously removed.
   *
   * @param array $element
   *   The form element.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   * @param array $complete_form
   * @return array
   *   The altered form element.
   *
   * @see \Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder::doBuildForm()
   */
  public function processForm(array &$element, FormStateInterface &$form_state, array &$complete_form) {
    foreach ($this->innerForms as $key => $inner_form) {
      $inner_form_state = static::getInnerFormState($form_state, $key);
      foreach ($inner_form_state->get('#process') as $callback) {
        // The callback format was copied from FormBuilder::doBuildForm().
        $element[$key]['form'] = call_user_func_array($inner_form_state->prepareCallback($callback), array(&$element[$key]['form'], &$inner_form_state, &$complete_form));
      }
    }

    return $element;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Form\FormValidatorInterface $form_validator */
    $form_validator = \Drupal::service('form_validator');
    foreach ($this->innerForms as $form_key => $inner_form) {
      $inner_form_state = static::getInnerFormState($form_state, $form_key);

      // Pass through both the form elements validation and the form object
      // validation.
      $inner_form->validateForm($form[$form_key]['form'], $inner_form_state);
      $form_validator->validateForm($inner_form->getFormId(), $form[$form_key]['form'], $inner_form_state);


      foreach ($inner_form_state->getErrors() as $error_element_path => $error) {
        $form_state->setErrorByName($form_key . '][' . $error_element_path, $error);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitterInterface $form_submitter */
    $form_submitter = \Drupal::service('form_submitter');

    foreach ($this->innerForms as $key => $inner_form) {
      $inner_form_state = static::getInnerFormState($form_state, $key);

      // The form state needs to be set as submitted before executing the
      // doSubmitForm method.
      $inner_form_state->setSubmitted();
      $form_submitter->doSubmitForm($form[$key]['form'], $inner_form_state);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Before returning the innerFormState object, we need to set the
   * complete_form, values and user_input properties from the main form state.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *   The main form state.
   * @param string $key
   *   The key used to store the inner form state.
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface
   *   The inner form state.
   */
  protected static function getInnerFormState(FormStateInterface $form_state, $key) {
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $inner_form_state */
    $inner_form_state = $form_state->get([static::INNER_FORM_STATE_KEY, $key]);
    $inner_form_state->setCompleteForm($form_state->getCompleteForm());
    $inner_form_state->setValues($form_state->getValues() ? : []);
    $inner_form_state->setUserInput($form_state->getUserInput() ? : []);
    return $inner_form_state;
  }

  /**
   * After the initialization of the inner form state, we need to assign it with
   * the inner form object and set it inside the main form state.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
   *   The main form state.
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface $form_object
   *   The inner form object
   * @param string $key
   *   The key used to store the inner form state.
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface
   *   The inner form state.
   */
  protected static function createInnerFormState(FormStateInterface $form_state, FormInterface $form_object, $key) {
    $inner_form_state = new FormState();
    $inner_form_state->setFormObject($form_object);
    $form_state->set([static::INNER_FORM_STATE_KEY, $key], $inner_form_state);
    return $inner_form_state;
  }

}
```

Comment: it's exactly what i need ! Thanks !!! I just need to modify it to have another display format ^^ Thanks !

Comment: It's hard to understand how works your code, did you use a tutorial to did that ? Because i try to understand it to remove the accordion system and show immediately the forms ^^

Comment: I created a module for drupal 8 that provides an entity reference widget that injects the references entity form into the main entity form (entity_reference_form). So I was aware of the potential problems.

Comment: How i can directly remove your accordion system and show directly the form ? And where can i edit the form to remove some fields for an example ?

Comment: Your original question has been answered. If you have questions about this code then we can continue on a chat thread http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40881/combining-multiple-form-objects-into-one

Comment: I need 20 and more rep to did that ^^ Did you know a link which contains the list of available attributes for a form field ? I find this to know all fields types but i didn't find one which show all the attributes available. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements