# Combining entity forms on one page breaks file upload

Tags: 8, entities, forms

In `Drupal 8` I have combined a number of custom entity forms on one page using this [example](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203405/how-to-combine-several-form-objects-into-one/271047#271047).
Everything works perfectly except for file uploads which do not load.

In the console it returns :

> XHR Loaded (product-application - 200 OK - 3.77340402601551s - 7.562KB) with the url: aslpd.dd:8083/products/product-application?element_parents=file_uploads/form/field_fu_1_photo/widget/0&ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax&regulatory_details[field_am_3_recordstatus]=draft&regulatory_details[field_am_16_commentstoapplicant][0][value]=&regulatory_details[field_am_17_regulatorsnotes][0][value]=&product_identification[field_pi_3_familyname][0][value]=&obj=O

It works perfectly when the form is on its own `(Not in the combined form)`.

Any ideas on why it breaks and how to fix?

After further investigation I have discovered it has to do with all ajax calls, the full form is sent to the ajax call ,not just the inner_form. This then causes issues with the return of the ajax data and the element it needs to replace. The ajax call executes correctly but on return it does not replace the element. Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Found the solution: created a new widget using the file widget as a base and then in the submit method the I needed to add the array element for the file uploads to all the getinputs() eg NestedArray::setValue($form_state->getUserInput()['file_uploads'], $parents, NULL); This would then return the correct values.